# Update query updates more than one value and error message Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, t-sql

table [dbo].[FileLoadStatus]

| FileName | RunningTotal |
| --- | --- |
| Transactions_104_19.03.2022.csv | NULL |
| ---------------------------------- | ---------------- |
| Transactions_127_20.03.2024.csv | NULL |

table [dbo].[Totals]

| SiteID | Total | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | 4465.76 | 19.03.2022 |
| -------- | ---------------- | --------------- |
| 127 | 6344.66 | 20.03.2024 |

When attempting to update the [FileLoadStatus] table's RunningTotal column from the [dbo].[Totals] table based on the siteID and Date fields, i encounter an error.

Also now I am getting the error message Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
UPDATE .[dbo].[FileLoadStatus]
    SET [RunningTotal] = (
      select DISTINCT 
       T.Total
     FROM .[dbo].[FileLoadStatus] FS
      Join .[dbo].[Totals] T
     on SUBSTRING([FileName],CHARINDEX('_',[FileName])+1,(((LEN([FileName]))-CHARINDEX('_', 
     REVERSE([FileName])))-CHARINDEX('_',[FileName]))) = T.SiteID
     and 
     left(right([FileName], charindex('_', reverse([FileName])) - 1),10) = T.Date
     
    );
```

Comment: Your UPDATE statement just reads "UPDATE RunningTotal in FileLoadStatus to .... *whatever value the subquery returns* " so every record will get updated with the same value if you subquery returns one value. **EDIT** your question to show sample data as text, and expected results based on that sample data. Explain how you calculated the results. This should be simple, but needs more clarity from you first.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery returns multiple values, which cannot be assigned to a single cell.

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE T1
SET [T1].[RunningTotal] = [T2].[Total]
FROM [dbo].[FileLoadStatus] AS T1
JOIN [dbo].[Totals] AS T2 
  ON SUBSTRING([FileName], CHARINDEX('_', [FileName]) + 1, (((LEN([FileName])) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE([FileName]))) - CHARINDEX('_', [FileName]))) = [T2].[SiteID]
 AND LEFT(RIGHT([FileName], CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE([FileName])) - 1), 10) = [T2].[Date];
```

Or

```
UPDATE [dbo].[FileLoadStatus]
SET [RunningTotal] = (
    SELECT [T2].[Total]
    FROM [Totals] AS [T2]
    WHERE SUBSTRING([FileName], CHARINDEX('_', [FileName]) + 1, (((LEN([FileName])) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE([FileName]))) - CHARINDEX('_', [FileName]))) = [T2].[SiteID]
      AND LEFT(RIGHT([FileName], CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE([FileName])) - 1), 10) = [T2].[Date]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've re-created some test data and added (for the 2nd example) a new record to show it working in case you have more than 1 entry per SiteID in the `Total` table.

I've also simplified the part where you extract the site id from the file name, but this was just for readability, it may not work on your real data.

```
DECLARE @FLS TABLE (FileName varchar(256), RunningTotal decimal(10,4))
DECLARE @Tot TABLE (SiteID int, Total decimal(10,4), [Date] date)

INSERT INTO @FLS VALUES
('Transactions_104_19.03.2022.csv', NULL),
('Transactions_127_20.03.2024.csv', NULL)

INSERT INTO @Tot VALUES 
(104, 4465.76, '2022-03-19'),
--(104, 1000.00, '2023-01-01'),
(127, 6344.66, '2024-03-20')

UPDATE f SET RunningTotal = t.Total
    FROM @fls f
        JOIN @Tot t ON CAST(LEFT(REPLACE([FileName], 'Transactions_', ''),3 ) as INT)  = t.SiteID

SELECT *     FROM @fls f
```

So this gives the following results

[image]

If I uncomment the second `Site 104` entry and run this version

```
UPDATE f SET RunningTotal = t.Total
    FROM @fls f
        JOIN (SELECT SiteID, SUM(Total) AS Total FROM @Tot GROUP BY SiteID)  t 
            ON CAST(LEFT(REPLACE([FileName], 'Transactions_', ''),3 ) as INT)  = t.SiteID

SELECT *     FROM @fls f
```

I get the following results

[image]